# Why is t distribution leptokurtic?

Tags: probability-distributions

Why is t distribution leptokurtic? It lies below normal and approcahes standard normal as degree of freedom increases so it should be platykurtic.

Comment: "Leptokurtic distributions are statistical distributions with kurtosis greater than three. It can be described as having a wider or flatter shape *with fatter tails*"

Comment: But peak of leptokurtic distributions are above normal and peak of t distribution is below normal